# social network relationship using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA from SPRING and I'm having trouble creating this relationship for a social network.

I was a little confused.

can someone help me with this relationship?

```
@Entity(name = "tbl_user")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<User> friends;
}

@Entity(name = "tbl_friendship")
public class Friendship {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @ManyToMany
    private User source;

    @ManyToMany
    private User target;
}
```

Comment: Help you how?  What's wrong with it?  What does it do now that it shouldn't do?

Comment: `Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.letsgo.domain.model.Friendship.source`

Comment: I have no idea how this relationship should be

Comment: Without knowing the true nature of the relationship it's difficult to answer. If you want a many-to-many from User to Friendship You would remove one of the @ManyToMany in Friendship and make the remaining one a Set<User>. An in implicit join table will be created as a result of this mapping. FYI, I would also change the User mapping to use a Set instead of a List. Set is the more performant collection to map many-to-many relationships. More information on mapping many-to-many relationships can be found here https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many.